# Magnetic Stripe Encoding on the fly?

Tags: design

I'm not exactly sure where this question would go, so I've decided to post it here. Hopefully you can help.

Using a smaller computing device (i.e. an Arduino or Raspberry Pi) and other outside tools, would it be possible to construct a magnetic stripe device with an extremely low coercivity so that its code could be changed on the fly by a computer and an encoding device? If this is possible, what devices would be best for this kind of project?

Comment: Are you asking about making a card encoder, a device used to record data onto an ordinary mag stripe card? Or are you asking about a device that simulates a magstripe card which can have the data recorded on the simulated card changed on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the dusty archives and find some stone tablets that mention *magnetic tape*.  That's how analog and then later even digital data was stored back in the Pleistocene, before steel tools, indoor plumbing, flash memory, and DVDs.

You will need something called a *tape head* to read and write data from/to a magnetic strip.  This is a coil wrapped around magnetic material with the ends brought together in a very small gap.  The gap is swept along the strip.  As the magnetic orientation stored on the strip changes, a small voltage is induced in the coil.

This process also works in reverse.  You drive the coil as the gap is swept along the strip to set the magnetic orientation of the small piece of the strip that is against the gap.

Comment: Yep... for a custom device disassembling a Walkman you'll obtain most of the circuitry you need. Using stereo recording you can use one channel as data and the other as clock, so no need for tricky swipe speed measurement. If you want to interface with "industry standard" magnetic stripe card (like credit cards), you'll need the 8-track tape recorder hardware; compact cassette heads are a little too narrow to record to the stripe reliably enough to be read by common card readers.